# WordPress Audio Player Stops Video Background

Tags: wordpress, audio, html5-video

I am building a WordPress site and the home page needs:
1. A video background that autoplays.
2. A sound track that autoplays in sync with the video, but can be paused or muted by the user. Ideally the audio would autoplay already muted.

The problem I'm having is that as soon as the audio player autoplays or is played manually, the video background stops.

Is there a different plugin or some custom code I can use to ensure the video background continues to play when the separate audio track starts?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

The site is available at: http://gsh.justprm.co.uk/

The theme is Salient: https://themeforest.net/item/salient-responsive-multipurpose-theme/4363266

The audio plugin I'm currently using is: https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-audio-player/

Answer (score 0):

I want to give you a simple solution that you can use. This solution wouldn't obviously work if you're keen to have both the video background and the audio as two separate elements on your site. But if otherwise, the solution I'm going to offer you will work perfectly.

1) Edit the homepage video you're using and add the music you want to play with it onto the video itself. So that the video's music will be the track you want to play.

2) Use slider revolution plugin to build your homepage slider and build the video slider.

3) Add an icon to mute/unmute the audio for the video playing on the slider. You can see how it's done here: https://www.themepunch.com/faq/add-a-muteunmute-button-for-video/

By these above steps, a) You will achieve perfect synchronization between the video and the audio b) You will load audio unmuted and STILL give the user to mute the audio and continue to play the video.

This is a non-technical, straight up easy solution.